# What causes an entry in my git config file for every LFS file I add?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-lfs

I recently added many (new) files to my git repository and am tracking them with Git LFS. My remote is BitBucket and it all works nicely as intended.

Except, for *every* file I add to LFS, an entry is added to my `.git/config` that looks like this:

```
[lfs "https://bitbucket.org/%7B%7D/%7B********-****-****-****-****6bcd1adc%7D/info/lfs/object/verify?upload_id=********-d87a-47f9-a857-ae04********"]
    access = basic
```

(All the `*`'s are hexadecimal characters I removed for security reasons)

Since one entry is added for every file I track and push with LFS and I have hundreds of files in LFS, my git config file is now huge.

I think this issue started after switching my `origin` remote (from one BitBucket repo to another).

**What's going on and more importantly, how can I fix this?**

**Can I safely delete these entries from `.git/config`?**

---

For reference, this is how the BitBucket remote is configured in the same config file:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repository.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[lfs "https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repository.git/info/lfs"]
    locksverify = false
    access = basic
[lfs "https://bitbucket.org/user/repository.git/info/lfs"]
    access = basic
```

And this is what the LFS part of `.gitattributes` in the root of the repo looks like:

```
...
database/seeds/sql/content/*/allcontent.sql filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
public/img/*/path1/*.normal@2x.jpg filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
public/img/*/path2/*.normal@2x.jpg filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

**Update**; I ran `git lfs uninstall` and then `git lfs install --local` in the repo to see if it fixes anything, it doesn't (that's to say, more lines were still being added to .git/config for new files I added to LFS). My `.git/config` file is now over 110KB large :S

**Update 2**: I was in touch with BitBucket, the only response I got so far is that this is expected behavior and something about pruning local LFS files, so I think they don't understand the issue I submitted. I *suspect* you can fix this the brutal way by removing the remote repository at BitBucket and all files tracked with LFS from your working directory, uninstalling Git LFS, removing the LFS directory from your Git repo, removing all `.gitattributes` lines that reference LFS, doing a new commit locally, using BFG or something like it to remove the references to all LFS-tracked files from all historic commits (depending on how you do it, this might make the tracked files go missing from all historical commits - I followed [this](https://dustinfreeman.org/blog/rip-lfs/) article), then re-installing Git LFS and re-tracking and adding the files before pushing to a repo newly created at BitBucket. I did just this but without the final step of re-installing Git LFS - for now I'll just stick to tracking those files the regular way. If using LFS is absolutely necessary I suspect these steps will fix it (at the price of possibly losing historical commit integrity) but I'm not sure either. If I get another response from BitBucket I'll be sure to update this issue.

**Update 3**: BitBucket now understands the issue and is investigating.

**Update 4**: BitBucket never got back to me. I chose to start over afresh and now have a repo that works well without the problem. No idea what was going on.

Comment: it looks like instead of just adding a tracked file for a single lfs repository, it's adding a complete entry for the url of the lfs repository, it might be something in the way lfs is configured, it does appear that the lfs urls in the .gitconfig do not match the ones configured in the repository.

Comment: Thanks for your reply JamesD! How would I go about configuring lfs or seeing what the current config is?

Comment: @JamesD you have any clue mate?

Comment: is this solved? I am having the same problem.

Comment: @Lane, no, I just started over with a fresh repo. BitBucket never got back to me.